# Checking if a string matches a value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I really need your help,

I would like to be able to check and see if a variable matches an array value and return true if it does.

ie.

```
var x = "ASFA"

var array = ["OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA", "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFB", "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFC"]

alert("true")
```

I was thinking of using this approach, but for the life of me, I cannot get it to return true, ideas?

```
function test() {

    var arr = ["OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA","OTHER-REQUEST-ASFB","OTHER-REQUEST-ASFC"]

    if ( $.inArray('ASFA', arr) > -1 ) {

        alert("true")

    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide some more detail?

Comment: Loop, check, repeat until found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows

```js
var x = "ASFA"

var array = ["OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA", "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFB", "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFC"]


array.forEach(function(ele){

console.log(ele.includes(x));




})
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy with ES6 :

```js
let x = "ASFA",
    array = ["OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA", "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFB", "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFC"],
    found = array.some(elem => elem.includes(x))
    
console.log(found)
```